# How to add element dynamically in angularjs without using directive?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, element

First of all, I'm new in Angularjs and not good at English.

I tried to add `<li>` by using `directive`, and below link is completed result of my first purpose.

[Add element using directive](https://jsfiddle.net/CRDeity/6kmszgL0/1/)

Second is passing value from `Controller` to `directive` or from `directive` to `Controller`, known as `two-way binding`.

But in this step, I couldn't figure out how to use `@`,`=` and '&'.

I guessed it's because of using `directive` in `directive`.

In my original code, my modal is made of `directive`, so `button directive` seems cannot get value from `Controller`.

I'm sorry I cannot show you my own code because I don't know how to make many `directive`s in fiddle.

.

.

I wanna know there are any way to add element dynamically without using `directive`.

No matter what you suggested like link, doc, or something, it'll be great helpful to me.

Just give a little attention please. Thank you. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may helpful.

You can use javascript as follows for achieving this.

https://jsfiddle.net/u08pa50z/

```
angular.module('myApp', [])


.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    var el = document.createElement("ul");
    el.style.width="600px";
    el.style.height="500px";
    el.style.background="green";

    var parent=document.getElementById("sib");    
    parent.appendChild(el);





    $scope.myFunc = function() {

        var ch = document.createElement("li");      
            el.appendChild(ch);

    };
  }]);
```

Comment: Oh!! this is what I want!! Sorry but, is it possible to put `directive` in `appendChild`? I can use this but my element is too long to adapt this.

Comment: use can use $compile for this. (https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1038684/AngularJs-Add-Remove-Directives-Dynamically-Save-D)[https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1038684/AngularJs-Add-Remove-Directives-Dynamically-Save-D]

Comment: Oh my!! You're my saviour!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can go with [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

> Fetches, compiles and includes an external HTML fragment.